# use the trust between Glassfish and Websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, single-sign-on, ibm-content-navigator

We have a web application in glassfish (Solaris with a Sun directory for authorisation ) , and Content Navigator ICN in Websphere (Linux with an OpenDJ directory)

I have experience in Writing Custom login screens,but this time there is going to be no password and I have to use the link from glassfish to open up Navigator with Trust .

I have gone through various documents with login scenairos,Still not very clear how to perform this , if any one can link a good tutorial or mention steps I need to take to make this work will be great.

I have good experience with java/Content Navigator etc can customize the login Function to work properly once I have the custom Scenario or Login Module etc ready,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> "I have to use the link from glassfish to open up Navigator with Trust ."

I believe you are referring to SAML here.
ICN doesn't (as far as I know) officially support SAML; however I have it currently running.  I used this guide here: [Lansche_Saml_guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1307_lansche/1307_lansche.html)

Basically, you need to get WAS configured to be an SP, and point it at your link to your trust (IdP).

When you deploy ICN, you have to change the "Content Navigator Authentication" setting to "Application server authentication". This is under the task Configure the IBM Content Navigator Web Application".

[image: auth]

I didn't need to create anything custom, other than a could java classes discussed in that link above.  The selection above tells ICN to skip it's login screen.